# How do I tell Sprockets 4 to compile assets for a vendored gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, sprockets

We have a Rails 5 application and recently updated Sprockets from the 3.x series to 4.0.2. Now Rails can't find an asset (CSS file) belonging to a vendored gem. Note that the gem is an engine and the asset is called from a template inside the engine.

The asset is referenced inside a file at `vendor/gems/our_vendored_gem/app/views/layouts/` like this:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "our_vendored_gem/application", :media => "all" %>
```

The file is at `vendor/gems/our_vendored_gem/app/assets/stylesheets/our_vendored_gem/application.css`

Then we get the error `Sprockets::Rails::Helper::AssetNotPrecompiled in OurVendoredGem::Mocks#index`.

Our `app/assets/config/manifest.js` looks like this:

```
//= link_tree ../images
//= link_directory ../javascripts .js
//= link_directory ../stylesheets .css
```

I tried adding

```
//= link_tree ../../../vendor/gems/our_vendored_gem/app/assets/stylesheets/ .css
```

...but that did not help. The vendored gem has a manifest file of its own but it is unclear to me if Sprockets is already reading it, or if it needs to be called somewhere.

What needs to happen to make this file available to Rails again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some digging, I found [this issue comment](https://github.com/rails/sprockets/issues/632#issuecomment-539724823) which explains that a Rails engine should have its own manifest file; that file can then be included in the application manifest like this:

```
//= link my_engine
```

This will find a manifest file at `my_engine/app/assets/config/my_engine.js` and add those directives to those in the application manifest.

Comment: This answer did solve my problem of resolving the location of Rails 5.1 engine assets (engines/*/app/assets/*) with Sprockets 4.0 on Rails 5.2.


As stated, the main (new) `app/assets/config/manifest.js file` contains a link directive to only the engine name (without the subdirectory). Then, by adding a new manifest file, within the engine's `app/assets/config directory`; being careful to (counter-intuitively) name the file `<engine_name>.js`.  One example is:


`engines/authentication/app/assets/config/authentication.js`

```
//= link_tree ../images
//= link_directory ...
```