# Sprockets 4 not loading javascript assets from Rails 7 engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-7, sprockets, rails-sprockets

##### TL;DR.

- Sprockets 4 isn't loading javascript assets properly from a Rails 7 engine.

##### Project Overview

- I am working on a Rails project, which is comprised of a `parent-app` and `engine-app`.
- Both have been upgraded to `rails (~> 7.0.8)` from `rails (~> 5.x)`.
- Both are now using `sprockets (~> 4.2.1)` and `sprockets-rails (~> 3.4.2)`.

  *NOTE: We chose to maintain using `sprockets` since it's a large production application already in use and would be too costly for us to port over to the new way of managing assets at this time.*
- The `parent-app` is almost bare bones. Most business logic, UI, and assets are within the `engine-app`.

## manifest.js

Sprockets 4 now requires a `manifest.js` to determine which top-level targets to compile ([documentation](https://github.com/rails/sprockets/blob/main/UPGRADING.md#manifestjs)).

##### parent-app

In `parent-app`, I created just such a file. Its contents are straightforward.

```js
// file: parent-app/app/assets/config/manifest.js

//= link_tree ../images
//= link application.js # has one line of code: `//= require_tree .`
//= link application.sass # has one line of code: `@import engine_app/application`
//= link engine_app_manifest.js
```

#### engine-app

In `engine-app`, I created a similar file with a different name. The name of the `manifest.js` in the engine can be anything from what I've gathered. This is based on information I gathered from the following SO posts:

- [How do I tell Sprockets 4 to compile assets for a vendored gem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64210874/how-do-i-tell-sprockets-4-to-compile-assets-for-a-vendored-gem)
- [Sprocket Rails V4 link to manifest files of external gems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77594886/sprocket-rails-v4-link-to-manifest-files-of-external-gems)

```js
// file: engine-app/app/assets/config/engine_app_manifest.js

//= link_tree ../fonts/
//= link_tree ../images/
//= link_directory ../javascripts .js
//= link_directory ../stylesheets .css
```

###### `link_directory ../javascripts`

There are several `.js` files in this directory that `require` other javascript. The most important of which is `application.js`. Here's a snippet.

```js
// file: engine-app/app/assets/javascripts/application.js

//= require babel/polyfill
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery.remotipart
//= require smart_listing
//= require underscore-dev

// ... and more

alert("HELLO WORLD!"); // added this to test if its being loaded
```

### Results

Based on the SO posts referenced above, this is all that should be needed to load assets from a vendor gem or engine, but it seems not only to work partially. The stylesheets from the `engine-app` seem to be loaded as the UI looks as it should. However, the javascripts are not.

There are `Uncaught ReferrenceErrors` being thrown and reported in the console. The `alert` message isn't being shown either. And when I look at the source files loaded using Chrome's DevTools, there are only a few files.

[image: parent-app-rails-7.0.8]

Contrast this to what's being loaded in the legacy app.

[image: parent-app-rails-5.x]

Comment: looks like it's working fine, if you have `<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>` in your layout that's the only file you'll see loaded in sources tab. you have an error `Uncaught ReferrenceErrors` that's why it never gets to alert line. remove all those `//= require` in application.js to test. also you might want to namespace your engine assets `engine-app/app/assets/javascripts/engine-app/application.js` so that it wouldn't clash with any other application.js files.

Comment: @Alex thanks for the response! I'm wondering if it's actually working because the Uncaught ReferenceErrors are coming from Javascript references to packages or classes that are defined within the engine. As far as I can see and tell, those package and classes are not being loaded. Also, thanks for the suggestion with the folder structure. I'll be sure to apply that once I get it working! :)

Comment: are you using gems to get jquery, babel, etc?

Comment: @alex yes it appears that way. They are all coming from the engine -- jquery-rails, jquery-ui-rails, select2-rails, etc.

Comment: @Alex I think you're on to something with your last comment. The error is emanating from a call to `I18n.globals` within an inline <script> which appears to be loaded by a gem. So I'm not exactly sure if it's compatible with Sprockets 4 and the manifest.js file. I'll have to do more research but if you have any tips, let me know!

Comment: if you can post the error log and which gem is causing it, I could take a look and see what's wrong.

Comment: @Alex There's really not much to it. In Chrome's DevTools console, I get the following error: `new?new_signup=1:20 Uncaught ReferenceError: I18n is not defined at new?new_signup=1:20:3` And at that line is this: `<script>I18n.globals = {};</script>`. We have two gems in the engine's gemspec related to `i18n`. They are `s.add_dependency 'i18n-js', '~> 3.9.2'; s.add_dependency "i18n-globals"` I've managed to get the sprockets to finally include `js` that's being linked in, and I can see calls to `I18n`, but I do not see `I18n` being defined anywhere or exported.

Comment: do you have `//= require i18n` or `//= require i18n/translations`? https://github.com/fnando/i18n-js/tree/v3.9.2?tab=readme-ov-file#rails-app-with-asset-pipeline

Comment: @Alex Yes, it's in the `application.js` of the engine (e.g., `/app/assets/javascripts/engine_name/application.js`) and that file is linked in `/app/assets/config/engine_name_manifest.js`

Comment: are you loading the engine application.js enywhere `//= require engine_name/application.js` or `<%= javascript_include_tag "engine_name/application.js" %>`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256673/discussion-between-john-and-alex).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sprockets directives in main app *application.js*:

```js
//= require engine_name/application.js
```

or load it directly, in this case this file has to be precompiled as well:

```rb
<%= javascript_include_tag "engine_name/application.js" %>
```

```js
// link for precompilation in any of the manifest files

//= link engine_name/application.js
```

`link` and `require` directives take asset name as an argument relative to `Rails.application.assets.paths`.

Your main issue was the use of `module` scripts, which changes the load order of the script:

```html
<script type="module">
  // module scripts are deferred and loaded after the page is loaded
  console.log("second")
</script>

<script>
  console.log("first")
</script>
```

---

Installation instructions for `i18n-js` don't require a module:
*https://github.com/fnando/i18n-js/tree/v3.9.2?tab=readme-ov-file#rails-app-without-asset-pipeline*

Also, note that you can add `type="module"` to any script tag if needed:

```js
<script type="module">I18n.globals = {};</script>
```